# Binding nested JSON to string in model

Tags: json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, model-binding

I'm trying to do something that seems like it should be simple, but I just seem to be missing something. I'm wanting to expose an API endpoint that takes JSON like this:

```
{
    "clientId": 1,
    "payload":{
        "some": "data",
        "someOther": "data",
        "even":{
            "more": "data"
        }
    }
}
```

And puts it into a model like this:

```
public class ClientJobCreateRequest
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string Payload { get; set; }
}
```

Where `Payload` ends up being `{"some": "data", "someOther": "data", "even":{"more": "data"}}`. The overall purpose is basically an API that acts like a proxy, it doesn't particularly care what's in `Payload`, it just needs to be able to pass it along with the metadata.

I've looked at implementing an `IModelBinder` for this, but it doesn't work since as far as Asp.net is concerned, Payload isn't a string, so it doesn't match.

Am I missing something obvious, or is this more subtle than I'm expecting?

Comment: Do you have control over the incoming Json?  Can you make Payload a string instead of an object?

Comment: would making Payload as object datatype acceptable?

Comment: @skimad Making it an object works fine. My brain wasn't working well yesterday and that didn't even come to mind.